# Hibernate with different object-constructors

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one hibernate/struts query that select distinct orders by telephone and mail.

```
 select.append("select distinct new no.projectname.domain.Order(ord.telephone, ord.email) from Order ord
```

and a constructor in Order:

```
public Order(String telephone, String email) {
    this.telephone = telephone;
    this.email = email;
}
```

I now want to create one (or two) queries where the user can select if he wants distinct phone or distinct mail

```
 if(phone) {
      select.append("select distinct new no.projectname.domain.Order(ord.telephone) from Order ord
 } else {
      select.append("select distinct new no.projectname.domain.Order(ord.mail) from Order ord
 }
```

But how can I make a constructor in object Order know that  I pass in a phone or email?

Is there a way to name constructors?
like this:

```
 select distinct new no.projectname.domain.Order.PhoneConstructor(telephone)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can do as below by using 3 constructors**

```
 select.append("select distinct") ;

    if(email != null && telephone != null) {
     select.append("new no.projectname.domain.Order(ord.telephone, ord.email)");
    } 

    else if(email != null){
    select.append("new no.projectname.domain.Order( ord.email)");
    }

    else if(telephone != null){
    select.append("new no.projectname.domain.Order(ord.telephone)");
    }

    else {        
    }

    select.append(" from Order ord");
```

Comment: The problem is the constructor in Order-object. It does not know if a mail or phone-numer is sent in.